# Асинхронный вызовы. Блокировка задач. AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, async-await, блокировки

Добрый день!
При вызове метода Set() в  AutoResetEvent в обработчике события (EndRequest) происходит полная блокировка всего приложения. Не могу понять почему. Уже голову сломал.:) Где может быть проблема?

Есть класс поставщика данных. У его есть функция делающая запрос к серверу данных и подписка на событие от сервера сигнализирующее об окончании загрузки данных.

```
// Класс поставщика данных
public class DataProvider
{
    // Поставщик данных
    private AnyServer _anyServer = new AnyServer(); 

    private AutoResetEvent _signal = new AutoResetEvent(false) ; 

    // Данные полученные с сервера
    private List<object> _returnData = new List<object>();

    void DataProvider()
    {       
        //Подписка на событие о завершении загрузки данных 
        _anyServer.EndRequestEvent += EndRequest; 
    }


    // ПРОБЛЕМА ЗДЕСЬ!?
    private EndRequest(int _numberRequest)
    {
        // Что то делаем ... Заполняем _returnData      
        // Сообщаем ожидающей задаче (ServerAddRequestAsync) что событие обработано,данные получены  и можено их возвращать.
        // !!!!! Вот здесь все и  останавливается ;(
        _signal.Set();      
    }

    // Функция запроса данных с сервера
    public async Task<List<object>> ServerAddRequestAsync(int param)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {           

                // Отрпавляем запрос на сервер
                _anyServer.GetData(param);

                //Ждем завершения события EndRequestEvent (EndRequest);
                // В реале доходим до этого этого момента. Дальше начинает отпрабатывать событие EndRequest. Как только выполняем _signal.Set(); все умирает.:(
                _signal.WaitOne();          
            }

            return _returnData;
    }
}
```

Далее есть ViewModel в котором есть команда привязання к кнопке во View (используется MVVM Light)

```
//ViewModel
public MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private DataProvider provider = DataProvider();

    // Команда "повешенная" на кнопку во View
    public RelayCommand<int> RunRequestCommand => new RelayCommand<int>(async p =>
        {
           await _runRequest(p, cts.Token);
        });

    private async  Task _runRequest(int param, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Можно так
        await Task.Run(()=>
        {
            for (......)
            {
                var resultCollection = provider.ServerAddRequestAsync(param).Result;
            }
        }

        // Или так:

        var resultCollection = await provider.ServerAddRequestAsync(param);
    }
}
```

После нажатия на кнопку программа виснет. Причем глухо.

---

Код работает. Проблема была в другом.

Comment: Написал свой класс AnyServer, для эмуляции. Проблема в чем то другом.


public class AnyServer
    {
        public event Action<int> EndRequestEvent;

        public void GetData(int param)
        {
            var th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                EndRequestEvent?.Invoke(param);
            }));
            th.Start();

            //Task.Run(() =>
            //{
            //    Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
            //    EndRequestEvent?.Invoke(param);
            //});
        }
    }

Comment: Твой код работает. Потоки не падают. И wpf и в console.

Comment: А у меня не работает :(

Comment: У меня получается следующая картина: _runRequest - Поток 1, await Task.Run внутри _runRequest - Поток 4, ServerAddRequestAsync - Поток 4, await Task.Run внутри ServerAddRequestAsync - поток 5, EndRequest - Поток 1. И когда я вызываю _signal.WaitOne() или _signal.Set() (бывает по разному) программа глхо виснет. В VS2017 при отладке в Задачах после зависания вообще ни чего нет.